Disable SSL certificate check in Cronet library
Is there a way to disable the SSL certificate check for Cronet network library similar to Retrofit Disable SSL certificate check in retrofit library ?
val cronetEngine = CronetEngine.Builder(ctx).build()

https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/cronet
